# How to set up non-trivial data persistence?

Tags: f#, functional-programming

Most generally, the question is: **how do you set up non-trivial data persistence in a nice functional way?**
I would much prefer answers from people with real experience, people who have actually done it. But I would also be happy to hear any other thoughts on the subject.

## And now, let me clarify what I mean with some examples.

Let's say I have some data that my program handles and needs to keep. Say, our old friend `Employee`:

```
module Employees =
  type Employee = { Name: string; Age: int; /* etc. */ }

module EmployeesPersistence =
  type EmployeeId = ...

  let getEmployee: (id:EmployeeId -> Employee) = ...
  let updateEmployee: (id:EmployeeId -> c:Employee -> unit) = ...
  let newEmployee: (c:Employee -> EmployeeId) = ...
```

Doesn't really matter how persistence functions are implemented, let's say they go to a relational database, or to a document-based database, or even to a file on disk. I don't care right now.

And then I have a program that does something with them:

```
module SomeLogic =
   let printEmployees emps = 
     let print { Name = name, Age = age } = printfn "%s %d" name age
     Seq.iter print emps
```

So far so straightforward.

Now, let's say I have another kind of data, `Department`, which is related to `Employee`, yet needs to be stored independently (in a separate table, separate collection, separate file).
Why independently? To be honest, I don't really know. What I *do* know is that it needs to have its own identity, so that I can display/update it without relation to any particular employee. From this, I infer that the storage must be separate, but I'm open to alternative approaches.

So I could do pretty much the same thing as I did with Employees:

```
module Departments =
  type Department = { Name: string; /* etc. */ }

module DepartmentsPersistence =
  type DepartmentId = ...
  let getDepartment, updateDepartment, newDepartment = ...
```

But now, how do I express the relationship?

### Attempt #1: ignore persistence.

In the great time-honored tradition of "abstract all the things", let us design our data model while pretending that there is no persistence. We'll add it later. Some day. It's "orthogonal". It's "auxillary". Or some such.

```
module Employees =
  type Employee = { Name: string; Age: int; Department: Department }

module SomeLogic =
   let printEmployees emps = 
     let print { Name = name, Age = age, Department = { Name = dept } } = printfn "%s %d (%s)" name age dept
     Seq.iter print emps
```

This approach means that every time I load an employee from persistent storage, I must load department as well. Wasteful. And then, `Employee`-`Department` is just one relationship, but in a real application I'd have a lot more than that. So what, do I load the whole graph every time? Prohibitively expensive.

### Attempt #2: embrace persistence.

Ok, since I can't directly include `Department` in `Employee`, I will include department's artificial identity, so I can load it when needed.

```
module Employees =
  type Employee = { Name: string; Age: int; Department: DepartmentId }
```

Now my model doesn't make any sense on its own: I am now essentially modeling my storage, not my domain.
Then, it turns out that "logic" functions that need department must be parametrized over the "loadDepartment" function:

```
module SomeLogic =
   let printEmployees loadDept emps = 
     let print { Name = name, Age = age, Department = deptId } = 
       let { Name = deptName } = loadDept deptId
       printfn "%s %d (%s)" name age deptName
     Seq.iter print emps
```

So my functions now *also* don't make sense on their own. Persistence has become an intimately integral part of my program, far from being an "orthogonal concept".

### Attempt #3: hide persistence.

Ok, so I can't include department directly, and I also don't like including its Id, what do I do?
Here's an idea: I can include a *promise* of department.

```
module Employees =
  type Employee = { Name: string; Age: int; Department: () -> Department }

module SomeLogic =
   let printEmployees emps = 
     let print { Name = name, Age = age, Department = dept } = printfn "%s %d (%s)" name age (dept()).Name
     Seq.iter print emps
```

So far this looks like the cleanest way (incidentally, this is what ORMs do), but still not without problems.
For one, the model doesn't exacly make sense on its own: some components are included directly, others via "promise", without any immediately evident reason (in other words, persistence *leaks through*).
For another, having department as a promise is fine for reading, but how do I update? I guess I could use lens instead of promise, but then it gets even more complicated.

### So.

How do people actually do this? Where should I compromise, what works, what doesn't? And do I really have to compromise, isn't there a "pure" way?
Since there are obviously real data-driven applications out there, there must be some way these things are done, right? Right?..

Comment: well as all those `()` and `unit`  in there probably tell you : this is just not a *functional* problem (there **is** no **pure** way to do this) as you are dealing with side effects everywhere - having said that the question is probably: how can I make something like this hidden in .net (as F# really is no different from any other language in .net here). And so all 3 of your attempts are already there in ORM world: 1) is eager loading, 3) is lazy loading and in 2 you just ignore the connection ;) ... as to the question what's better? Well *sorry* but that *depends* on your situation

Comment: but maybe I can help you out a bit with *my opinion*: I think the DDD way is a good idea - search for bounded contexts in your domain and check if you can load aggregates in there completely into memory and go with 1 - usually that's no problem, in your example that would mean: yeah you should load the departments information with your employee but in the employee-context you should probably not load all the other co-workers in that department as well (so you might get another `Department` model in the department-context later)

Comment: My very point is that I don't want to make it "hidden". Ideally, I want my model independent of persistence. Realistically, I want an approach that would fit well with F# (and ORM doesn't fit this criterion).

Comment: the answer to that is good old POCO (if you want POR - plain-old-records here) - this really is a common problem in your enterprisey OOP world too, and for once I think the solutions there are rather good ;)

Comment: About your DDD suggestion: I thought about this as well at some point, and as you correctly pointed out, this leads to multiple models for same things depending on context (i.e. department either with employees or without). Is this ok, does it work out? Wouldn't that explode over time?

Comment: indeed this works out rather well (of course the main point is finding the domain-language and using it too for your problem - it's almost more a means of communication with domain-experts) - there are even some really great talks about the idea of DDD with F# - but those usually don't include the persistance layer because that normally is nothing more than ORM

Comment: But ORM works with mutable objects, doesn't it? This alone would not fit well with F#. Do you really just write C#-style code with `<-` everywhere?

Comment: you just have to "map" those nasty objects back to your domain-records/objects (yeah I know ... pain)

Comment: So what I'm hearing is, "find good aggregates, load/update them together, multiple models are fine, and use ORM as lower level data access technology". Would that be correct?

Comment: yes that's the way I usually do it - it's not optimal as you have to do similar stuff multiple times but it decouples the infrastructure from the domain-models but it works fine for medium to large projects - but remember that is **my** opinion and this is the part where you enter highly opinionated terrain (there are quite a few who are happy with the entities from EF and/or use model-first EF too - but for me this leaks to much)

Comment: @FyodorSoikin I don't know whether *normal* mutability is required. For WebAPI `[<CLIMutable>]` is sufficient for most JsonSerializers, maybe there's an ORM that could handle that too?

Comment: Move the relation to a separate type.

Comment: It seems `[<CLIMutable>]` is supported at least by EF.